# Allocating more memory to Eclipse

Tags: memory, eclipse

I have a lot of memory available on my computer and I was wondering if I can give my **Eclipse** - which I use heavily - more memory.

How much is enough? Respectively how much brings any additional effect?

I am talking about editing the eclipse.ini file:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx768m
```

Should I simply double (quadruple) all the numbers? Or just the Xms and Xmx? I don't know what is what there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can experiment with different values for `-Xms` and `-Xmx` start with `-Xms1024m` and `-Xmx2048m` and see if that helps.

Another thing you can try is different garbage collection strategies and a whole lot of other jvm settings. I suggest visiting this question over on Stack Overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse